# Подсчёт количества постов в 1 рубрике WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Вставил в functions.php вот такой код, чтобы можно потом было вывести шорткод, но он не работает, что пошло не так?

```
function count_cat_post($category) {
  if(is_string($category)) {
    $catID = get_cat_ID($category);
  }
  elseif(is_numeric($category)) {
    $catID = $category;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  $cat = get_category($catID);
  return $cat->count;
}

function wp_my_shortcode( $atts ) {
  echo  count_cat_post('29');
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_output', 'wp_my_shortcode');
```

Comment: `echo  count_cat_post('29');` => `return  count_cat_post('29');` и покажите как используете его, если не поможет

Comment: что вы передаете в функцию count_cat_post название категории или id категории?

Comment: @DarthKYL передаю айди категории

Comment: @InDevX теперь ничего не выводится, а раньше просто название шорткода, прогресс. `function count_cat_post($category) {
  if(is_string($category)) {
    $catID = get_cat_ID($category);
  }
  elseif(is_numeric($category)) {
    $catID = $category;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
  $cat = get_category($catID);
  return $cat->count;
}

function wp_my_shortcode( $atts ) {
  return  count_cat_post('29');
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_output', 'wp_my_shortcode');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашей функции `count_cat_post` есть проверка на переданный параметр если параметр строка то вы ищите `id` категории через ее название используя функцию `get_cat_ID`, но так как вы передаете в шорткод `id` категории то аргумент
функции `count_cat_post` должен быть типом `integer` соответственно вместо строки `'29'` нужно передать число `29`, пример ниже:

```
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode_output', 'wp_my_shortcode');

function wp_my_shortcode( $atts ) {
  return count_cat_post( 29 );
}

echo do_shortcode( '[my_shortcode_output]' );
```

подробнее о создании шорткодов вы можете прочить по этой [сслыке](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_shortcode)

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!